# How to store tree structure in lucene index

Tags: java, search, lucene

Instead of storing a flat structure, I have tree structure to store in lucene index. While doing a search on tree, I have to return search node as well as all ancestor of that node.

For ex, tree is like below. Its complete geography tree.

```
      Global
      |    |
     Asia North America
     |     |        |
 China    USA      MEXICO
```

I can think of two ways to store this data in lucene.

```
1st approach: Capture on parent node of a given node.
       name, parent
       Asia, Global
       China, Asia
       USA, North America

Java Object:
Class Node
     id ,name
```

In this approach, lets say I am searching for USA. As per requirement I have to return all ancestors of USA which North America and Global. So I have to do go index in recursive manner.

```
2nd approach: store ancestors in lucene index also

Java Object:    
    class Node
    id, name, List<Node> ancestors
```

In this approach, I am capturing ancestors multiple times. Will it create an issue or lucene captures the duplicate values only once ?

Which approach would be better or is there a another good to store tree kind of structure in lucene ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store tree data in a Lucene/Solr/Elasticsearch index or a NoSQL db?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970193/how-to-store-tree-data-in-a-lucene-solr-elasticsearch-index-or-a-nosql-db)

Comment: The solutions in link caters to multiple tree in lucene. I have only one tree.